# OpenCV compilation error in Fedora 21

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, opencl, fedora

I've got OpenCV source code from github and I get the following error when trying to compile it:

```
/lib64/libavutil.so.54: undefined reference to `clReleaseMemObject@OPENCL_1.0'
/lib64/libavutil.so.54: undefined reference to `clReleaseCommandQueue@OPENCL_1.0'
/lib64/libavutil.so.54: undefined reference to `clCreateBuffer@OPENCL_1.0'
/lib64/libavutil.so.54: undefined reference to `clBuildProgram@OPENCL_1.0'
/lib64/libavutil.so.54: undefined reference to `clSetKernelArg@OPENCL_1.0'
/lib64/libavutil.so.54: undefined reference to `clGetDeviceIDs@OPENCL_1.0'
/lib64/libavutil.so.54: undefined reference to `clEnqueueUnmapMemObject@OPENCL_1.0'
/lib64/libavutil.so.54: undefined reference to `clGetPlatformInfo@OPENCL_1.0'
/lib64/libavutil.so.54: undefined reference to `clCreateProgramWithSource@OPENCL_1.0'
/lib64/libavutil.so.54: undefined reference to `clGetDeviceInfo@OPENCL_1.0'
/lib64/libavutil.so.54: undefined reference to `clReleaseContext@OPENCL_1.0'
/lib64/libavutil.so.54: undefined reference to `clCreateContextFromType@OPENCL_1.0'
/lib64/libavutil.so.54: undefined reference to `clCreateCommandQueue@OPENCL_1.0'
/lib64/libavutil.so.54: undefined reference to `clEnqueueMapBuffer@OPENCL_1.0'
/lib64/libavutil.so.54: undefined reference to `clGetPlatformIDs@OPENCL_1.0'
```

My machine is a laptop with Intel i7 and a GT630M graphics card and I'm using Bumblebee.

Thanks.

Comment: You're not linking against the OpenCL library. Do you have OpenCL installed? Is the command line pointing to the lib correctly?

Comment: The make file is generated using cmake and the libOpenCL.so file is in library path.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?  I'm running into the *exact* same issue right now in CentOS 7 when attempting to install OpenCV 3.1.  I read that it may be necessary to compile a new version of ffmpeg, but the steps required to do that are dizzying.

Comment: Nope. As far as I remember I've just disabled OpenCL support :(. Compiling ffmpeg is really dizzying.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to have CUDA 8.0 installed, this is caused by Nvidia's careless packaging for it, which puts `/usr/local/cuda-8.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib` ahead of `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` during compile time and run time.

The quick fix is to use:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu make
```

Source: https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2/issues/804